# How to make array of SKSpriteNode and then display them on the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make an array of SKSpriteNode's and then I am trying to render them on the screen.  This is how I am trying to do this but it is not working:

```
var alienShip : [SKSpriteNode] = [SKSpriteNode]()



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = SKColor.white
    alienShip.append(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "alien1"))

    alienShip[0].position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.5)
    addChild(alienShip[0])

}
```

Comment: Whats size of array  after adding images

Comment: Do not set the position for alien ship just yet.  I am going to guess that you are rendering them off screen because your scene size is wider than your screen size, so 0.1 * width will not be noticable.  Either that or during didMove, your scene size is still at 0,0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to assign the alienShip a size.  You gave it a position but the scene can't add it because it doesn't know where.  Try something like: 
    `alienShip[0].size = CGSize(width: size.width 50, height: 50)` before adding it to the scene.

Comment: This can't be the answer, alienShip size would be based on the image size alien1

Comment: Okay.  Worked for me though.  But, also they were partly off screen, so I did bring position down as well.

Comment: Not sure what “worked for you” means.  That is like taking a blow torch to a lock and saying you got in your house.  Yes, it worked, but you now have extensive damage, and your solution to get into your house is cumbersome and may not work every time.

Comment: I just mean I was able to render the sprites on the screen with his/her code and this one extra line.  Not sure what you mean by "extensive damage" and "cumbersome and may not work every time".  It is working every time without errors and I don't think it's too cumbersome to the machine to assign a spritenode a size.

Comment: because what are you going to do in a new project with an even larger screen size?  Are you going to keep guessing random size numbers until your sprite appears again?

Comment: No, your answer is just plain wrong, there is no difference in question.

Comment: I understand what you're getting at.  This answer isn't really an answer, just a work-around.  Your comment about scene and screen sizes not matching is probably more accurate.